# Prove that $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ is differentiable at $c$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded function and $g:I \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function differentiable at $c \in I$ and $g(c)=g'(c)=0$.  Show that $h(x) := f(x)g(x)$ is differentiable at $c$.

My work so far:  as $f$ is bounded we have $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in I$ then,

$$\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)g(x)-f(c)g(c)}{x-c}$$

$$\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)g(x)}{x-c}=\frac{f(x)g(x) - f(x)g(c) + f(x)g(c)}{x-c}$$

$$f(x)\left( \lim_{x \to c} \frac{g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}\right) + f(x)g(c) \left( \lim_{x \to c}  \frac{1}{x-c}\right)$$

$$\lim_{x \to c} f(x)g'(c)  + g(c) \left( \lim_{x \to c}  \frac{f(x)}{x-c}\right) $$

$$g(c) \left( \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{x-c} \right)$$

I'm not sure how to deal with that last limit, any  help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
h'(c)
&=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{h(x)-h(c)}{x-c}\\
&=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)g(x)-f(c)g(c)}{x-c}\\
&=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)g(x)-f(x)g(c)+f(x)g(c)-f(c)g(c)}{x-c}\\
&=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)[g(x)-g(c)]}{x-c}+\lim_{x\to c}\frac{[f(x)-f(c)]\overbrace{g(c)}^{=0}}{x-c}\\
%&=f(c)g'(c)+g(c)\lim_{x\to c}\frac{[f(x)-f(c)]g(c)}{x-c}
\end{align*}
In particular, the last limit written is zero, while $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)[g(x)-g(c)]}{x-c}=f(c)g'(c)=0$
thus your limit exists and it is zero.

Comment: That's what I thought at the start, but isn't that technically $\frac{0}{0}$?

Comment: The definition of derivative is always (when dealing with continuous functions) a limit of the form $0/0$.

Comment: Yeah and when applying the definition of derivative you have to show that limit exists.  My question is how do we know that the zero makes the whole limit zero and not \frac{0}{0} which is undeterminant

Comment: Look at the last passage I wrote; the first limit clearly exists, the second one exists too and is zero because the function on which we pass to the limit is identically zero (since $g(c)=0$)

Answer (score 2):

Note that (since $g(c)=0$) the last limit you wrote can also be written as

$$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\frac{g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}$$

Since $f$ is bounded and $g'(c)=0$, this limit will also be zero.

p.s - be careful with notation - you can't pull out only part of the function when $x\to c$, so technically, your last limit is wrong.

Comment: I realized that the last limit was completely wrong it shouldn't be $g(x)$ on the outside it should be $g(c)$ which makes your trick not work I believe.